# C# ExecuteReader fails if condition

Tags: c#, sql-server

Why only the else condition runs? Postalcode column is `float`, City column is `nvarchar`. I think the fail is the string may be mistake.

```
private void txt_st_postalcode_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mypublicip\\SQLEXPRESS2017;Initial Catalog=studentreg; User = myusername; Password=mypassword;"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT City FROM Cities WHERE Postcode=@Postcode", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", "10101");

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                string txt_st_postalcode = reader.Read() ?
                reader[1] as string : ("City");

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    txt_st_city.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("City"));
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sh*t!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two calls to reader.Read(), if your query returns only one record the second call will always be false. By the way, Is this code your real code? _reader[1]_ will throw an IndexOutOfRange exception because you retrieve only one field (City). There is no second column in your query

Comment: if a single row is returned, the first reader.Read() will return true and the second one false, so the else condition will always be executed with 1 row. It will only be executed when 2 or more rows are returned. You'll get an error on the second reader.Read() if no rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how these postcodes work (different in the UK), but given that you're using `ExecuteReader` you appear to be expecting multiple results.  As the comments have pointed out, you're currently reading the results twice; however, you should probably have some form of loop; for example:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT City FROM Cities WHERE Postcode=@Postcode", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", "10101");
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string txt_st_postalcode = reader[0] as string;

            //txt_st_city.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("City"));
            // Depends what you're doing here?
        }
    }
}
```

If you only expect a single result, try using `ExecuteScalar()` which will return a single result; for example:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT City FROM Cities WHERE Postcode=@Postcode", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", "10101");
    txt_st_city.Text = command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Well, the answer now is correct but still the query returns a City not a PostalCode as it assumed from the receiving textbox name, probably the query is not like the OP has presented here.

Comment: This program will student registartion form. the user typing the correct postal code to postal code textbox. When user leave (leave event) the textbox then select city from postalcode where postalcode = what user given. That result print out to city textbox. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Yeah - just realised in the original question it sort of looks like there was once / still is a query returning city and postcode.

Comment: @Steve makes a good point here - if you are actually returning more than one field from your query then ExecuteScalar will not work (well, it will work, but it may not do what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you need to read PostCode from the reader, you have to select first. So, change your query.

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT City, PostCode FROM Cities WHERE Postcode=@Postcode", connection))
```

Secondly, calling `read` once per row before getting data.

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    txt_st_postalcode .Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PostCode"));
    txt_st_city.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("City"));
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sh*t!");
}
```

Comment: Runs onto a sh*t with this solution. It may not be the problem that Postalcode column is float and the city column is nvarchar in SQL table?

Comment: Is it possible that your query returns nothing?